# Why does adding the same thing flip recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I really don't understand.

how come if I do this

```
void printStars(int lines,int lines_org){
 int i;

 if (lines>0){
    for(i=0;i<lines-1;i++)
        cout<<" ";
    for(i=lines-1;i<lines_org;i++)
        cout<<" *";
    cout << endl;

 printStars(lines-1,lines_org);

}
        }
```

it prints out this //it appears I can't post images

```
   *

  * *

 * * *

* * * *
```

but if I just add that first part back onto the end it flips it

```
void printStars(int lines,int lines_org){
 int i;

 if (lines>0){
    for(i=0;i<lines-1;i++)
        cout<<" ";
    for(i=lines-1;i<lines_org;i++)
        cout<<" *";
    cout << endl;

 printStars(lines-1,lines_org);

 for(i=0;i<lines-1;i++)
        cout<<" ";
    for(i=lines-1;i<lines_org;i++)
        cout<<" *";
    cout << endl;

}
        }
```

and I end up with this?! //it appears I can't post images

```
   *

  * *

 * * *

* * * *

* * * *

 * * *

  * *

   *
```

Why is it flipped?

I don't understand recursion

Comment: You can post text, and your output is text, so there's no need for an image.

Comment: When I posted the text it didn't show up correctly

Comment: You can format it by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button or pressing ctrl+k. That should make it show up. Or just wrap it in `<pre>` and `</pre>`

Comment: Wrong tag, clearly `c++` and not `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's split your function into 3 parts:

```
 void printStars(int lines,int lines_org){
      int i;

      if (lines>0){
         // P1: Print the stars.
         for(i=0;i<lines-1;i++)
             cout<<" ";
         for(i=lines-1;i<lines_org;i++)
             cout<<" *";
         cout << endl;

         // P2: Recurse. 
         printStars(lines-1,lines_org);

         // P3: Print the stars, again.
         for(i=0;i<lines-1;i++)
             cout<<" ";
         for(i=lines-1;i<lines_org;i++)
             cout<<" *";
         cout << endl;
     }
 }
```

Your function will recurse like this:

```
 P1
     |->P1
     |      |->P1
 P2--+->P2 -+->P2
     |      |->P3
     |->P3    
 P3
```

`P1` and `P3` are identical, so they must produce the same output, right? So, it prints the stars, recurses and then print the same set of stars again. So, whatever you get on the first line, you'll get on the last line. Whatever you get on the second line, you'll get on the line before the last line...

Let me explain in another way. Try to open your recursive function step by step:

Step 1: 1_star (recurse) 1_star

Step 2: 1_star (2_stars (recurse) 2_stars) 1_star

Step 3: 1_star (2_stars (3_stars (recurse) 3_stars) 2_stars) 1_star

Step 4: ...

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it. I wrote all the code but I couldn't for the life of me understand why it worked
 "P1 and P3 are identical, so they must produce the same output, right? So, it prints the stars, recurses and then print the same set of stars again. So, whatever you get on the first line, you'll get on the last line. Whatever you get on the second line, you'll get on the line before the last line..." 

That was the most simplistic answer. Thank you so much it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

**First lets go through this example**:

```
void printStars(int lines, int lines_org) {
    int i;

    if (lines > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < lines-1; i++)
            cout << " ";
        for (i = lines-1; i < lines_org; i++)
            cout << " *";
        cout << endl;

        printStars(lines-1,lines_org);
    }
}
```

Based on your output I can tell you called it as `printStars(4, 4);`:

- After the function is called `lines` is `4` and `lines_org` is also `4`. This will cause the first for loop to produce 3 `" "` and then the second loop to produce a single `" "`. The result is `"     *"`
- The function will call itself after the loops and now this time `lines` is `3` (`lines_org` is still `4`) so it produces 3 `" "` and 2 `" *"`. The result is `"    * *"`
- The function calls itself again, `lines` is now `2`, and so the result is `"   * * *"`
- The function calls itself again, `lines` is now `1`, and so the result is `"  * * * *"`
- The function calls itself again, `lines` is now `0` and so the code inside the conditional statement is not executed. As a result `printStars` is not called and so the function returns
- After returning it goes back to when `lines` was `1`. That returns to when `lines` was `2`. That returns to when `lines` was `3`. That returns to when `lines` was `4`. Finally that returns to when you called `printStars(4, 4);`

**In the second example**:

```
void printStars(int lines, int lines_org) {
    int i;

    if (lines > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < lines-1; i++)
            cout << " ";
        for (i = lines-1; i < lines_org; i++)
            cout << " *";
        cout << endl;

        printStars(lines-1, lines_org);

        for (i = 0; i < lines-1; i++)
            cout<<" ";
        for (i = lines-1; i < lines_org; i++)
            cout << " *";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The recursion goes like this:

- The first couple of loops result in `"     *"` and then `printStars` is called just like the first example. However, this call occurs before the next couple of loops
- Just like the first example the result is `"    * *"`. Again `printStars` is called before the next couple of loops
- Just like the first example the result is `"   * * *"`. Again `printStars` is called before the next couple of loops
- Just like the first example the result is `"  * * * *"`. Again `printStars` is called before the next couple of loops
- Just like the first example `lines` is now `0` and so the conditional statement is not executed and the function returns
- Now that the function has returned to when `lines` was `1` the second couple of loops are executed resulting in `"  * * * *"`
- The function where `lines` was `1` returns to when `lines` was `2`. The second couple of loops results in `"   * * *"`
- The function where `lines` was `2` returns to when `lines` was `3`. The second couple of loops results in `"    * *"`
- The function where `lines` was `3` returns to when `lines` was `4`. The second couple of loops results in `"     *"`
- The function where `lines` was `4` returns to when `printStars(4, 4);` was called